# How to add values of one map to another iteratively in scala?

Tags: scala

```
var imgResults:Map[String,String] = null

val previewList= LitmusService.checkStatus(testId)

var previewStatus = "false"

previewList.foreach (applicationId => {
  if (previewList.length == 29) {
    imgResults += (LitmusService.fetchResults(applicationId, "full_on"))
    previewStatus = "true"
  }
  else if ((previewList.isEmpty().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
    previewStatus = "falseAll"
  }
  else {
    imgResults += (LitmusService.fetchResults(applicationId, "full_on"))
  }
  contentType = "application/json"
  JsonUtility.toJSONString(Map("status" -> previewStatus, "images" -> imgResults))
})
```

The fetchResults() function returns Map[String, String]. I need to add the values it returns to the map imgResults over the foreach loop. However I am getting an error :

```
Error:(336, 50) type mismatch;
 found   : Map[String,String]
 required: (String, String)
        imgResults += (LitmusService.fetchResults(applicationId, "full_on"))
                                                 ^
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: never assign `null` to anyone

Comment: yeah so how else can i initialise it? do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you're adding so many unnecessary parentheses... `(previewList.isEmpty().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("true"))` could easily be simplified to `previewList.isEmpty.toString.equalsIgnoreCase("true")`...

Comment: @ElectricCoffee  only `previewList.isEmpty` is enough

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti this is true... empty lists can't contain anything, good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a type error is because you try to add the wrong type.

`fetchResults` returns a `Map`, the `+=` operator on a `Map` doesn't add one `Map` to another, rather it adds one key-value pair to the `Map`.

```
myMap += (k -> v)
myMap += (k, v) // both valid
```

Which means you can do one of the following 2 things:

Continue using `+=`

```
for(kv <- LitmusService.fetchResults(applicationId, "full_on")) {
  imgResults += kv
}
```

Or be super lazy and use the map concatenation operator `++=` and do this:

```
imgResults ++= LitmusService.fetchResults(applicationId, "full_on")
```

Though mind you that `++=` doesn't add to the end, not that it matters much given the nature of a Map:

```
val a = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2)
val b = Map('c -> 3, 'd -> 4)

a ++= b // a is now Map('b -> 2, 'd -> 4, 'a -> 1, 'c -> 3)
```

Another thing to note. Never ever initialize with `null`, it's unsafe and it's very bad practice. Instead you should instantialise it with

```
val imgResults = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]()
```